# Can I use Visual Studio 2010 and not upgrade to .NET Framework 4.0?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, target-framework

I have many Visual Studio 2008 web projects targeted at the .NET Framework 3.5.  I want to start using Visual Studio 2010, but the .NET Framework 4.0 isn't very well supported by web hosting companies just yet.  It seems to make sense to stick with the .NET Framework 3.5 for now.  If I open my projects in Visual Studio 2010 and leave them targeted at the .NET Framework 3.5, am I going to have problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 supports [multitargeting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197.aspx) which means that you can target .NET 3.5SP1 with it.  See the page for more specific details.

Comment: Just be warned, if you share your development with others, once you upgrade, even though the application wil be 3.5, the project will require vs 2010.

Comment: When I upgraded the project to Visual Studio 2010, I was surprised to see that it changed a lot of files, including my web.config.  I presume everything will work OK, but it makes me a little nervous.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can you can set your target in your project properties and you shouldn't run into any problems.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, VS 2010 support developing in .net 2.0 3.5 and 4